DY-SV5W Voice Playback Module
Link to DY-SV5W data sheet
Currently making a box with 12 buttons, each of which will trigger a certain sound file.
I have put the module in I/O Integrated Mode 0 (Key Combination Playing).
Do not want to use an arduino or another board to control via UART
Pins on device shown in Fritzing Image as Reddit table formatting turned into nonsense.
To minimise amount of connections to each pin I thought this would be best way to get 12 separate audio files to play

The problem I am having is figuring out best way to connect Buttons 9 - 12. These will require connecting to two of the IO pins. Want to still be able to press button one and trigger only IO 0 and not the Button 9 connections (IO 0 and IO 1) because of the way I have wired.
All the buttons are simple SPST arcade style switches. Know there'll be a simple solution but best asking the experts as haven't done anything like this for a while
Attempted to draw up on fritzing...


You don't appear to have any pull-up resistors on the chip inputs that connect to the control switches. It's quite likely that they will be needed. There may be other problems but, you haven't posted a full schematic nor a link to the data sheet. Lack of pull-ups is enough to make an answer of course.

Have added link to data sheet at top.
Haven't included the board schematic but basically if I ground (connect to pin 10) one of the IO Pins (pins 1 - 8) it will play a file

Pullups are likely included in the chip, making external pullups unnecessary.

Pulling down two lines with one button will require some diodes.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
When drawn as a square matrix like this, you can see that you can pull down any combination of lines with each switch.
If the forward drop of a regular silicon diode is too much (I doubt it), you could try Schottky diodes.

I’ll order some diodes and give this a go, will update on progress, thank you Dave
